# Taking a screenshot of the window in the background

Tags: winapi

Will it be any problems to take a screenshot of the window content, if that window is overlapped by some other application.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible / easy with [PrintWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162869(v=vs.85).aspx) (user32.dll). For a detailed code example, see [Capturing Windows Regardless of Their Z-Order](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/g-m/gdi/capturingimages/article.php/c11231).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've got a method in the application to render it to an off-screen bitmap you'll only get the visible portions of the window.

Answer (score 0):

You could hide the top window, then do the screenshot. 
In autohotkey: use [winhide](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinHide.htm):

```
WinHide, window_name
```

your snapshot code here, then

```
 WinShow, window_name
```